# Difference of MediaRecorder results with `audio/webm;opus` in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, webm, opus, web-mediarecorder

I want to convert Blob coming from `ondataavailable` handler into `AudioBuffer`. When executing the following code, in Chrome, the result differs from what I wanted, the result in Firefox.

```
  const { ... } = useMediaRecorder({
    onDataAvailable,
    mediaStreamConstraints: { audio: true },
    mediaRecorderOptions: {
      mimeType: 'audio/webm;codecs=opus',
      audioBitsPerSecond: 8000,
    },
  });

  const onDataAvailable = (data: Blob) => {
    if (!data.size) return;

    data.arrayBuffer().then((audioSegment) => {
      console.log(arrayBufferToString(audioSegment));
    });
  };
```

Utility function:

```
function arrayBufferToString(buffer: ArrayBuffer) {
  return Array.from(new Uint8Array(buffer)).map((x) => x.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join(' ');
}
```

The typical results in Firefox were one of the following three types: starts with the EBML header `1a 45 df a3 ...`, the cluster section header `1f 43 b6 75 ...`, or the `SimpleBlock` header `a3 ...`.

```
0th: <header start>1a 45 df a3 ... <cluster start>1f 43 b6 75 01 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff e7 81 06 <block start>a3 10 00 00 14 82 00 00 00 08 0c ...
1st: <block start>a3 10 00 00 10 82 02 58 00 08 0f 05 44 3f 1b 12 2d ...
...
sometimes: <another cluster start>1f 43 b6 75 01 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff e7 81 xx <block start>a3 10 00 ...
```

However, in Chrome, the result was totally different: I cannot find no patterns there (besides the 0th response starts with the EBML header and the cluster section header), except every response ends with `a3`.

```
0th: <EBML header>1a 45 df a3 9f 42 86 81 ... <cluster>1f 43 b6 75 01 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff e7 81 00 <block>a3 aa 81 ... 08 84 88 67 48 ec a3 e2 84 00 9f bc ef ac 6f e1 b0 26 3c 7a 48 da 1d 61 68 3b f3 71 d2 37 a1 26 1f c5 f2 42 1f 35 ed 23 db 80 a3
1st: b0 81 02 57 80 18 e0 bb 8c 9a ... 1d 62 fc be 26 ee 8d 08 4f db 5f a3
2nd: b6 81 04 eb 80 18 e3 c7 eb 3d ... bb 69 13 89 86 df 72 12 20 fb 80 a3
```

With Firefox's result, I can get `AudioBuffer` by prepending the header part (plus the cluter section header part) to the array buffer data. And this did not work with Chrome's. How can I achieve the same result also with Chrome?

---

I attach the hex data of first 4 responses below. (arraybuffers)

```
1a 45 df a3 9f 42 86 81 01 42 f7 81 01 42 f2 81 04 42 f3 81 08 42 82 84 77 65 62 6d 42 87 81 04 42 85 81 02 18 53 80 67 01 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 15 49 a9 66 99 2a d7 b1 83 0f 42 40 4d 80 86 43 68 72 6f 6d 65 57 41 86 43 68 72 6f 6d 65 16 54 ae 6b bf ae bd d7 81 01 73 c5 87 f9 97 11 7f 25 cb d1 83 81 02 86 86 41 5f 4f 50 55 53 63 a2 93 4f 70 75 73 48 65 61 64 01 01 00 00 80 bb 00 00 00 00 00 e1 8d b5 84 47 3b 80 00 9f 81 01 62 64 81 20 1f 43 b6 75 01 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff e7 81 00 a3 aa 81 00 00 80 18 01 1f b5 a1 8e 77 d0 94 7e f2 51 d4 27 ab 85 44 89 db c0 6e 20 1c 0a 45 1b a9 08 47 d6 0c 36 bb 06 48 65 76 b0 a3 ab 81 00 3b 80 18 4e 38 e6 94 89 0a 9b 7e b6 84 e1 56 f2 61 df 3a c1 7b e3 8c 40 ca 25 16 d9 14 61 d3 f2 cd 37 92 23 d0 44 19 10 d0 a3 a3 81 00 77 80 18 01 6d ba a9 a8 b7 1b 6f eb 6d 1c 9a f6 8a 9a cd 62 bf 9d 1a 20 8f 83 95 c3 f4 97 77 57 c0 a3 a9 81 00 b3 80 18 61 6d af 08 fb c8 4a 2e 8f 9c d6 da 5d fc f3 a2 c1 e2 74 13 fd cd 11 b4 29 5b ed 8d 4b 91 dd b7 09 4c 04 40 a3 ae 81 00 ef 80 18 e0 9b 5c 22 a9 6a 4d a2 cf 41 21 27 53 aa e7 8c 4d b7 d0 a7 d2 08 62 8a db a2 7d ff 50 65 4e da 25 2e 82 40 1b 45 ee cb a6 a3 b7 81 01 2b 80 18 e3 47 86 7f 79 28 31 2a 31 eb 3a c5 97 a3 01 69 24 f3 c0 bf 1c b2 50 53 db 0c 58 30 6e 20 c2 ce 40 46 27 e9 7d 62 f9 db 02 70 d1 f7 af a2 fd d6 1c 80 a3 af 81 01 67 80 18 c3 92 78 3e 99 12 19 93 ef c2 d0 2e 0b 1d 96 49 15 5e 30 26 33 1d 2a 94 74 43 1d e8 6d f9 10 4c 99 b1 cc 3a fb b0 75 dc 6f f0 a3 a4 81 01 a3 80 18 01 70 e8 ca 1f ef b0 46 ba 56 18 14 92 28 fa 6b 9e 5f 11 65 39 c8 32 ad 84 cc ac 59 e8 2c 04 a3 b0 81 01 df 80 18 21 66 c2 d1 7d b1 e8 0c 2a bc 56 4a 87 b6 fa d1 f3 98 de 4c cb 62 5f 95 00 c1 2d eb 16 92 40 c7 04 b9 37 d3 d3 d5 e4 cd 07 53 84 a3 bc 81 02 1b 80 18 ea 65 1d 27 ac 51 69 0d 8d d5 d4 53 0d 08 84 88 67 48 ec a3 e2 84 00 9f bc ef ac 6f e1 b0 26 3c 7a 48 da 1d 61 68 3b f3 71 d2 37 a1 26 1f c5 f2 42 1f 35 ed 23 db 80 a3

b0 81 02 57 80 18 e0 bb 8c 9a dd b9 41 9b 5c 15 9f 90 77 d4 2d 74 d0 79 07 4e 55 a5 3f f2 48 ca f6 c8 b3 b9 a0 ba db 40 ce 6d eb 88 a2 b6 92 44 68 a3 c6 81 02 93 80 18 e3 ad 30 c8 6a 70 66 da 4a c4 35 20 e0 f8 04 a0 52 3e 79 16 f8 bd 43 bb d7 6f c8 2a 22 f3 af ce 36 ba 9e 09 f0 7f 9a da 91 ce 23 79 e1 e0 97 a0 f9 22 b0 fd 49 96 12 d7 52 a6 5b 06 93 6d 7a a0 80 a3 b7 81 02 d0 80 18 ec db a0 d0 92 7c 40 f3 43 5c b5 64 6c 9a 79 fb 35 63 b9 ef 2f 83 d2 a5 fe b3 c2 2d f5 52 6e 93 58 60 1e d6 79 e5 23 0f d7 6b 19 8d b7 a7 92 3e 9d 98 a3 c0 81 03 0b 80 18 e3 9f a7 2c a8 bd 1b 22 d3 1d e9 3a ad 19 86 52 8b 41 64 48 e7 18 da e0 1a 24 49 6b 16 1d c2 10 f5 fb d5 69 03 38 6f 9d ef dd b7 42 b9 62 44 06 59 a9 68 a6 c0 60 4b 85 e6 c6 20 a3 bc 81 03 47 80 18 e0 d6 9d 95 ce 7d b4 a5 96 a7 f9 12 4c dd 9b ed b4 04 18 fe 59 46 ba 04 cb 04 bc 1d 22 2a cc df ba b8 b9 11 e3 e9 f5 47 e3 58 69 ce c0 ab cc e5 1f d0 b7 34 a7 1a 80 a3 aa 81 03 83 80 18 0f 06 65 0c 30 3c bc 2b 84 eb 04 93 a6 0d c7 77 c8 d5 67 7e cc 44 f2 36 3d 8c 82 67 3a d7 1d 31 80 f4 7e 5d 50 a3 bc 81 03 bf 80 18 e3 47 61 0e ef b9 82 6b 75 de 9c 52 16 fe b5 62 aa 16 c5 ee ed 3b dd 39 d8 1a 0a 60 7f c2 54 df 57 02 5f 30 2b 96 c4 59 6b 2c a1 fa 3f 38 cc 1a 47 7e 25 80 07 3e 80 a3 c7 81 03 fb 80 18 e9 95 39 93 13 fb 2b de 8f ac 2e 70 ce 99 c5 97 f7 96 64 0c 0a 9c 25 9c 9c 8f e8 b5 1e e9 fb e5 cc 0f fc 77 4b 13 c5 97 10 70 07 9d 68 8e 7f 0e 17 be f6 45 e7 82 36 e1 fe 55 c0 53 af 52 24 52 37 78 a3 ba 81 04 37 80 18 e3 cf 96 59 39 cf 53 52 32 8d 50 23 de 32 0d dd 66 fb 16 98 b4 d5 38 cc 8f 47 fe 23 9b 93 25 ab 74 82 87 72 b4 67 f9 b2 c2 0c 65 21 50 e7 92 6a ec 5a 96 6d d8 a3 b7 81 04 73 80 18 e1 1b c1 42 95 97 28 e8 e9 7a f0 87 0e 20 15 a7 4c c0 e1 b5 c4 49 ca 4d 4b f6 ee b1 ed 2a 4b cd 6c 85 64 91 33 d2 fb 4d 0d c2 14 af e3 88 ec 4c a5 70 a3 bb 81 04 af 80 18 e1 34 99 96 04 92 35 a8 93 6f 90 1a ad 1e 8f 5b b9 0b d6 5c 4f 01 13 49 c7 2e 86 9a 2e 80 d5 e6 9c 45 66 de 00 b4 5f 28 41 2b 44 1d 62 fc be 26 ee 8d 08 4f db 5f a3

b6 81 04 eb 80 18 e3 c7 eb 3d 54 c3 76 1e 00 21 9a f3 dc fe d9 ff fe 0e 98 6e d6 11 f1 fe c8 01 3e 11 51 8d a4 95 ce b2 69 0a 00 84 d8 c9 f0 62 0b 93 48 32 8d ab b5 a3 c1 81 05 27 80 18 ef a3 a0 d4 20 18 39 6f 08 23 a7 8c f9 99 9a a5 85 82 fd 41 c5 e6 90 20 94 86 a6 ab be f8 2a 2b 0d e6 08 a2 ef 5f be 39 c0 68 fb 30 c1 bd 3b cd eb 6b 69 14 ed 60 ce 35 ff e8 2e 30 a3 b5 81 05 63 80 18 e4 98 df da 76 7f 47 98 16 a0 ca 79 b4 f4 87 53 6c 4d d4 c4 2b 0d 31 6e b9 ab 87 45 18 15 38 35 b5 e1 f5 70 81 58 ef 25 32 18 48 56 94 5f 3b 20 a3 a6 81 05 9f 80 18 01 7d 6c da a1 fb 9b 6a 1b ec 28 d0 da c4 45 bb aa 12 5d 4a 00 a2 4f e0 a2 eb 68 47 ad cb ad 8e 80 a3 c4 81 05 dc 80 18 e0 95 b6 2c 29 0a cd 6e 88 e6 e1 9b 17 4b e9 d0 95 96 0b 1e 9e ac 93 ee c6 5b ef 57 81 65 d8 12 87 7f 88 8a d2 05 f6 08 93 22 9a c9 68 d0 19 aa 86 de e4 cc b1 1f 14 d0 3b 76 5e 4b a9 45 a0 a3 ca 81 06 17 80 18 ec 0c 8e 49 14 88 98 5d 00 5f ee 4b 5d 04 1e d1 07 69 0d 3c 18 9d ed 53 d9 c5 85 a4 3c 5d 16 df 7a 7c 2a 21 87 21 46 cc 6c 54 c1 38 96 58 14 77 98 78 f1 cc c6 66 79 42 bb ba f8 ed 8e 6e 0b 85 a9 51 58 9a 08 a3 bb 81 06 53 80 18 ef a9 b3 48 0e e2 e7 f0 1b 4d c6 cc 9c 38 f8 e7 35 34 e0 e9 71 d6 d7 34 dd 10 37 7f 9a 2e ef de 6f 9a c4 fd 12 14 70 cd 3a 15 27 0f df 83 10 e3 9c 0b 39 ee 99 69 a3 b7 81 06 8f 80 18 e3 f2 58 35 78 0f cb 1e 7a 03 e9 6b 34 75 5e 11 d8 10 12 cb da 89 04 2a 82 6e 92 bb dd 00 b7 1c 62 83 27 7d 86 c0 a4 d4 40 55 fb ca 4e 36 f1 2a a6 f4 a3 b3 81 06 cb 80 18 c3 f2 8d f7 0b 17 d3 66 3d 37 01 b8 76 43 26 62 e5 1b a8 17 fa 3e cb af 5a ef c8 c2 2e 72 53 8c d2 e6 ae a3 60 b4 57 19 b0 1f bf bf df b8 a3 ab 81 07 07 80 18 0e a7 01 48 bb 4d c8 96 6b 7e f2 bd cc e4 e8 17 ba c1 56 06 09 d8 90 1f d8 ce 11 bb 69 13 89 86 df 72 12 20 fb 80 a3

a5 81 07 43 80 18 01 67 48 74 06 ce d5 79 61 77 87 2f 5d 3c 19 95 fc 6b d5 2a 10 ba 65 6c da 98 c4 77 cd 4b 95 80 a3 ad 81 07 7f 80 18 0e 37 fa e4 9c 13 f4 16 63 78 db 7f ca bb 8a cf 05 05 fe 7e 80 05 d3 c4 a5 63 06 21 23 a1 d8 be a2 84 38 2a 24 d1 e9 ac a3 b7 81 07 bb 80 18 6e a1 8d 67 a9 6c 91 65 99 fe 9a b6 6e 73 7c 9a 85 9e 62 af fe 81 64 c8 21 d4 dd cd 93 22 84 28 ad 31 e2 68 d1 96 10 ce 77 4f 70 24 b5 e6 ad b0 bc 59 a3 c2 81 07 f7 80 18 e0 d8 4d 73 05 70 6a 30 5b 20 8d d1 4a af 0c ca de 79 39 15 d4 52 f0 f2 40 96 25 9e e0 9a b9 54 39 cc 05 1e c7 7f 8d bb e8 3e fa 3f 9c 4a cd 28 9b 65 6d 98 86 27 be 54 09 0d df c8 48 a3 b7 81 08 34 80 18 eb 32 93 0d 4d 28 22 ed 2d 2f 37 ba fa de dc 1e aa 64 e9 6f 22 a3 39 6c 83 d7 8e f0 3e 61 0a e6 13 f7 97 c8 55 fa c4 5e ed 12 f7 d0 8e 20 7f c9 25 80 a3 b5 81 08 6f 80 18 6e 7f 41 7c c9 ae 77 e2 d0 52 b1 13 ca 05 1c 25 d2 bf a3 7c 88 e3 50 cd 54 ff da 06 e7 c5 04 0d 4b 9e 23 40 51 1f bb c8 b9 9e c8 0d b9 78 8f 70 a3 ba 81 08 ab 80 18 e0 e2 48 bd 1d 1d c2 30 be 1c d0 88 3b c6 5d d4 69 b7 45 b7 a4 2a e4 7b 9f ca 6d d6 bd 0d 68 cd 2d d4 a6 27 96 15 ba 7f c2 5c 52 df c1 5d f8 be 3d 67 a5 90 b0 a3 c4 81 08 e7 80 18 e4 86 6f 04 1a 8e d8 63 51 fb 5e 22 2f 06 55 9b 72 28 9f 38 fb ef 64 00 a8 2e e1 1d cc 71 58 1f 40 d3 92 b3 4f 6a 47 55 42 9a 93 e2 91 5a 65 62 e7 ab f6 6f 79 ae 85 ce 00 8a 11 72 b1 63 40 a3 cb 81 09 23 80 18 eb 60 33 17 f2 61 df fc 44 9e bd d3 3b f2 ec f7 10 aa d2 b5 dc a2 df 5f a7 43 81 12 2a 1e 09 17 62 1a 4d 07 9b c3 dc d5 0a 3d f1 e5 5b 91 54 af a4 d1 e5 8a 05 df c2 80 d4 ea 89 10 cc 35 df 6a 86 9d 07 fd 1a 24 a3 c7 81 09 5f 80 18 ee a3 cd c2 87 bc d9 9b 74 ee 78 6f df 35 c8 4b 60 0f 39 6f 75 57 dc 88 61 64 7e e1 3e 7f 58 08 4e e2 d7 f2 e0 6e 09 b0 a5 73 b5 0e c4 19 81 5f 55 99 0b 82 67 10 0c 50 8b 56 13 38 ae 22 16 e5 b6 f6 a3 b5 81 09 9b 80 18 ee 8a 61 32 ed ef 73 c6 2f 09 03 8b 43 db 0f be 87 c5 c4 f1 73 be 5a 5e 18 6f f9 04 8a 05 34 f2 e0 e6 80 8b 21 e4 3a c9 cd f7 b4 5e e1 f9 1d 7c a3
```

Answer (score 0):

The `a3` suffix was actually the SimpleBlock header for the next block... I just moved them to the front and everything worked well.

Comment: I have the same issue now.  Could you give more details about how you do the movement?  Thanks.